# Creating a new thread that _really_ runs in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, blocking

I have the following Code in a class:

```
def persistDBThread(self):
    while True:
        Thread(target=self.__persistDB)
        time.sleep(10)

def  __persistDB(self):
    with open(self.authDBPath, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(self.authDB, outfile)
```

The thread gets started in the __ main__ but as soon as I start this thread it is actually blocking in the main execution.

Why is this? I know about the GIL - it's all in the same process. Task switching happens in the same process in micro-thread, but why doesn't it switch back?

Thanks!

Sorry for even asking:

```
def persistDBThread(self):
    Thread(target=self.__persistDB).start()


def  __persistDB(self):
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        outfile = open(self.authDBPath, 'w')
        json.dump(self.authDB, outfile)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `__persistDB` too soon.  Use `target=self.__persistDB` with no parentheses at the end.  When you include the parentheses, you are calling the function *before* the threading call is made.  Without the parentheses, you pass the function as an argument to be called later.

You will then need to call the resulting `Thread` object's `start` method.  This is all described in [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html), which you should read.

Also, don't run that in a `while True` loop.  That will just create endless numbers of threads as you call `Thread` again and again.  Google or search StackOverflow for "Python threading example" to find many examples of the right way to use the `threading` module, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/python-multithreading-for-dummies).

Comment: Sorry! Actually i was just tinkerin with the code, i had it like that aswell, and still it doesnt switch.

Comment: Corrected my mistake in the question.

Comment: I def. made a mess, somehow shut down my brain. Thanks for taking your time!